# Web service access error in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, dll

I have got a SOAP web-service from a third party client.
trying to integrate the service, added as  service reference. I could able to access and call all API functions in a test desktop application.

Same code , i have taken for create a .dll file, where i am getting an error as follows.

*{"Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ServiceReference.' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element."} System.InvalidOperationException*

1. WEB API refereed as Service Reference

I have no access to source code of the API.

Can any one tell me about this error perpendicularly happen  in a DLL project.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code? The test desktop application you mention, was this provided by the vendor for testing? Have you got access to the source code. Lastly, you can try Postman to test the API to see that it all works as expected.

Comment: @Snympi, friend this desktop app i have created , and i can test the API successfully . 
What i did was, 
Added a reference > Add service_reference  .
Using the Object of service_reference , i call the API_method with values required.
I got correct result.

same code when i use in DLL project , then it throws error.

Comment: It could be that the client configuration is saved in the DLL project config file and not the config file of the application using the assembly. Try copying the same section from the config file in the DLL assembly project to the main project. Let me know if this works - I'll add this comment as an answer.

Comment: @Snympi, dear you gave me good thread to work around.
It was the problem in <system.serviceModel> binding , the endpoint.
Actually i missed to add the binding in the referral project.
It works now. Thank you , you can mark this as answer.

Comment: I've submitted the answer. You have to mark it as answer pls.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the client configuration is saved in the DLL project config file and not the config file of the application using the assembly. Try copying the same section from the config file in the DLL assembly project to the main project.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any access of API code, then please follow below steps.

1. Remove URL from your project config (Not Must)
2. Try to add harcoded URL of service when you making the client object in your code before deploy DLL.(It's bad practice, but you told that you don't have any access of API Code)

Hopefully this should work